# Looking for assertURLEquals

Tags: python, unit-testing

During a unittest I would like to compare a generated URL with a static one defined in the test. For this comparison it would be good to have a TestCase.assertURLEqual or similar which would let you compare two URLs in string format and result in True if all query and fragment components were present and equal but not necessarily in order.

Before I go implement this myself, is this feature around already?

Comment: @gefei because 'http://a.b/?foo=bar&fez=baz' != 'http://a.b/?fez=baz&foo=bar'

Comment: so can you parse the query string into a dict, compare the dict and the  rest of the URL?

Comment: Yea it would be trivial to implement this in python, which is why I thought certainly it must be around already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is something built-in, but you could simply use `urlparse` and check yourself for the query parameters since order is taken into account by default.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url1 = 'http://google.com/?a=1&b=2'
>>> url2 = 'http://google.com/?b=2&a=1'
>>> # parse url ignoring query params order
... def parse_url(url):
...   u = urlparse.urlparse(url)
...   q = u.query
...   u = urlparse.urlparse(u.geturl().replace(q, ''))
...   return (u, urlparse.parse_qs(q))
... 
>>> parse_url(url1)
(ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='/', params='', query='', fragment=''), {'a': ['1'], 'b': ['2']})
>>> def assert_url_equals(url1, url2):
...   return parse_url(url1) == parse_url(url1)
...
>>> assert_url_equals(url1, url2)
True
```

Comment: Setting yours to accepted since it also took fragment into account.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not too hard to implement with [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) in the standard library:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs


def urlEq(url1, url2):
      pr1 = urlparse(url1)
      pr2 = urlparse(url2)
      return (pr1.scheme == pr2.scheme and
              pr1.netloc == pr2.netloc and
              pr1.path == pr2.path and
              parse_qs(pr1.query) == parse_qs(pr2.query))

# Prints True  
print urlEq("http://foo.com/blah?bar=1&foo=2", "http://foo.com/blah?foo=2&bar=1")
# Prints False
print urlEq("http://foo.com/blah?bar=1&foo=2", "http://foo.com/blah?foo=4&bar=1")
```

Basically, compare everything that is parsed from the URL but use parse_qs to get a dictionary from the query string.